# VB.NET - FTP upload/download integrity issues

Tags: vb.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have a Windows service that periodically uploads files to an FTP server, and will then redownload the file to check that the bytes match exactly. For most files it seems ok, but one of the files we're using recently is a 10mb CSV file and the files are always slightly different (by a couple of bytes).

Below are the upload, download and file compare methods. Note that the Download is setting UseBinary as true but the upload isn't - could this be why?

```
 public string Upload(FileInfo fi, string targetFilename)
    {
        //copy the file specified to target file: target file can be full path or just filename (uses current dir)

        //1. check target
        string target;
        if (targetFilename.Trim() == "")
        {
            //Blank target: use source filename & current dir
            target = this.CurrentDirectory + fi.Name;
        }
        else if (targetFilename.Contains("/"))
        {
            //If contains / treat as a full path
            target = AdjustDir(targetFilename);
        }
        else
        {
            //otherwise treat as filename only, use current directory
            target = CurrentDirectory + targetFilename;
        }

        string URI = Hostname + target;
        //perform copy
        System.Net.FtpWebRequest ftp = GetRequest(URI);

        //Set request to upload a file in binary
        ftp.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        ftp.UseBinary = false;

        //Notify FTP of the expected size
        ftp.ContentLength = fi.Length;

        //create byte array to store: ensure at least 1 byte!
        const int BufferSize = 2048;
        byte[] content = new byte[BufferSize - 1 + 1];
        int dataRead;

        string result = null;

        //open file for reading
        using (FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead())
        {
            try
            {
                //open request to send
                using (Stream rs = ftp.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        dataRead = fs.Read(content, 0, BufferSize);
                        rs.Write(content, 0, dataRead);
                    } while (!(dataRead < BufferSize));
                    rs.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                result = URI + " - " + x.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                //ensure file closed
                fs.Close();
            }

        }

        ftp = null;
        return result;

    }
    #endregion

  public bool Download(string sourceFilename, FileInfo targetFI, bool PermitOverwrite)
    {
        //1. check target
        if (targetFI.Exists && !(PermitOverwrite))
        {
            throw (new ApplicationException("Target file already exists"));
        }

        //2. check source
        string target;
        if (sourceFilename.Trim() == "")
        {
            throw (new ApplicationException("File not specified"));
        }
        else if (sourceFilename.Contains("/"))
        {
            //treat as a full path
            target = AdjustDir(sourceFilename);
        }
        else
        {
            //treat as filename only, use current directory
            target = CurrentDirectory + sourceFilename;
        }

        string URI = Hostname + target;

        //3. perform copy
        System.Net.FtpWebRequest ftp = GetRequest(URI);

        //Set request to download a file in binary mode
        ftp.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        ftp.UseBinary = true;
        ftp.UsePassive = false;

        //open request and get response stream
        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                //loop to read & write to file
                using (FileStream fs = targetFI.OpenWrite())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                        int read = 0;
                        do
                        {
                            read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        } while (!(read == 0));
                        responseStream.Close();
                        fs.Flush();
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        //catch error and delete file only partially downloaded
                        fs.Close();
                        //delete target file as it's incomplete
                        targetFI.Delete();
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                responseStream.Close();
            }

            response.Close();
        }


        return true;
    }

Public Function FileCompare(ByVal file1 As String, ByVal file2 As String) As Boolean

        ' Checks to see if two files are the same
        Dim file1byte As Integer
        Dim file2byte As Integer
        Dim fs1 As FileStream
        Dim fs2 As FileStream

        If file1 = file2 Then
            Return True
        End If

        fs1 = New FileStream(file1, FileMode.Open)
        fs2 = New FileStream(file2, FileMode.Open)

        ' Simple length test
        If fs1.Length <> fs2.Length Then
            fs1.Close()
            fs2.Close()
            Return False
        End If

        Do
            file1byte = fs1.ReadByte()
            file2byte = fs2.ReadByte()
        Loop While file1byte = file2byte And file1byte <> -1

        fs1.Close()
        fs2.Close()
        Return ((file1byte - file2byte) = 0)

    End Function
```

Comment: Are the bytes that are different the first two or three characters of the file?  The reason the binary vs non-binary method is causing a problem is that the first two characters indicate the file is `Unicode` - `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` or `0xFE 0xFF`.  Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: I've just checked and it's not, however the one difference seems to be a strange unicode character. The server it's being sent to does not support unicode so I think that's why